# Publishing as major version fixes issue?

Tags: version-history

I have a file that was not responding to attempts to check it out. Version history showed 6 major and 934 minor versions of 17.5 MB file. I published later as major version and appears to work. Why does publishing as major version change behavior? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It must have been locked by someone in your team, SharePoint doesn't usually show that on screen. Publishing a major version must have overridden the lock. It happens sometimes when users try to edit a document through Office applications without explicitly checking them out from browser.